# Can I stop UIImageView Animation at last frame?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an animation using a UIImageView:

```
myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;
myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 1;
myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[myAnimatedView startAnimating];
```

How can I tell to animation to stop at the last frame (keeping the last image in the series visible)?

Answer (score 75):

the image property on the UIImageView class has the following docs:
"If the animationImages property contains a value other than nil, the contents of this property are not used."

So the trick to hold on the last frame of an animation in iOS4 is to first set the image property to that last frame (while animationImages is still nil), then set the animationImages property and call startAnimating. When the animation completes, the image property is then displayed. No callback/delegate needed.

Comment: I just tried this on iOS5 it works. I put `animation.image = [myAnimatedView.animationImages lastObject];` right before `[myAnimatedView startAnimating];` and the animation stops at the last image.

Comment: That doesn't make sense from that documentation; if it did what it said then assigning image wouldn't do anything.  The docs are wrong--the image property *is* used, while the image isn't animating.

Comment: Just to clarify: mahboudz' solution works even with PNGs or GIFs with transparent parts. The "main" imageView.image only comes into effect _after_ the animation has run, and does not "shine through" transparent parts during the animation if set at this point (tested on iOS 5, 6, 7).

Answer (score 16):

You can set image of last frame to your UIImageView instance and then when animation will finish last frame image remains visible. Here is the code:

```
// create your array of images
NSArray *images = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"video1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"video2.png"]];
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
imageView.image = images.lastObject;
imageView.animationImages = images;
imageView.animationDuration = 1.0; // seconds
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: what you will do if all images are png( transparent ), then the background image clearly you can see

Answer (score 6):

After the animation finishes you can set your UIImageView image to the last frame of your animation.

```
myAnimatedView.image = [myAnimatedImages objectAtIndex:myAnimatedImages.count - 1]
```

I don't think there is a delegate method that would notify you on animationFinish event so you would need to start a `NSTimer` with same duration as the animation to get the notification.

[UIImageViewAnimation documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/)

Comment: You can actually forget about the `NSTimer` - as long as your image is animating, the `animationImages` will display until the animation is finished, then the `image` will display.

Comment: This actually no longer works on iOS4, FYI. Trying to figure out a workaround but my app works fine on 3. Seems like animationImages clears the image property now.

Comment: Same here, my application suddenly got buggy with iOS 4. And there is no delegate to let me put the correct image back again.

Answer (score 3):

Swift version will be as given below but in objective-c logic will be same
you can hack it just setting the `image` of the `UIImageView` to the last image of the images array. just before the code of animation, like `imageView.image = arrayOfImage.last`
the whole logic is given below

```
        imageView.image = arrayOfImage.last //(this line create magic)
        imageView.animationImages = arrayOfImage
        imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
        imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        imageView.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 1):

I just toss a UIView holding the first frame on top of the animation UIView...
make the animation view hidden and set it's image as the last frame...
and then have them switch hidden properties during the process.

```
so... just before your last line...
// quickly hide the view that only holds the first frame
myOtherView.hidden = YES;
// start the animation
[myAnimatedView startAnimating];
// show the animation view
myAnimatedView.hidden = NO;
// BAM, done. It will use the last image when it ends.
```

Less code, more IB, whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved this by creating a subclass of UIImageView, overriding startAnimating() and setting the image property to be the last image in your image array before you call super.startAnimating(). 
This in addition to setting the animationRepeatCount to 1 achieves the desired effect.

Here is my Swift class:

```
class SuccessAnimationImageView: UIImageView {

var duration: NSTimeInterval = 2

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    setupImages()
}

override func startAnimating() {
    setLastFrame()
    super.startAnimating()
}

func setupImages() {
    animationImages = ImageHelper.successAnimationImages
    image = animationImages?.first
    animationRepeatCount = 1
}

func setLastFrame() {
    image = animationImages?.last
}
}
```

Comment: Yes its important that it is set before the call to `startAnimating()`. Setting `self.image` *after* calling `startAnimating()` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Was having issues in start/stop animation & managing animation count So used [this](https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu) pod

```
imageViewObject.animate(withGIFNamed: "gif_name", loopCount: 1) {
        print("animating image")
}
```

To start/stop animation :

```
imageViewObject.isAnimatingGIF ? imageViewObject.stopAnimatingGIF() : imageViewObject.startAnimatingGIF()
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you set the removedOnCompletion property of the rotation animation to NO, 
e.g.,
rota.removedOnCompletion = NO;

That should leave the presentation layer where it was when the animation finished. The default is YES, which will snap back to the model value, i.e., the behavior you describe.
The fillMode should also be set,

i.e.,
rota.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

Answer (score -1):

You can Stop the animation by setting the UIImageView property
`animateImg.animationDuration = 1`