# How do I get an image array animation to cycle through only one loop in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, animation

I have an image array animation, however it is a continuous loop. How do I get it to cycle through only one loop and stop on the last frame?

```
- (void) balloonAnimation
{
    NSMutableArray *balloonAnimationImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:27];

   for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
       NSString *nameOfImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"balloons%d.png", i+1];
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:nameOfImage];
       [balloonAnimationImages addObject:image];       
    }

    //animate here
    self.imgBalloon.animationImages = balloonAnimationImages;
    self.imgBalloon.animationDuration = 5.0f;
    [self.imgBalloon startAnimating];    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.imgBaloon.animationRepeatCount = 1;
```

EDIT:
As @Elliott Perry stated in his answer, you need to assign the last frame to the `image` property. Here is the code:

```
self.imgBalloon.animationImages = balloonAnimationImages;
self.imgBalloon.animationDuration = 5.0f;
self.imgBaloon.animationRepeatCount = 1;
self.imgBaloon.image = [balloonAnimationImages lastObject];
[self.imgBalloon startAnimating];
```

Comment: That works but how do I get it to stay on the last frame?

Comment: Thanks Adam for the update. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

From [Can I stop UIImageView Animation at last frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776516/can-i-stop-uiimageview-animation-at-last-frame)

> The image property on the UIImageView class has the following docs: "If the animationImages property contains a value other than nil, the contents of this property are not used."
>
> So the trick to hold on the last frame of an animation in iOS4+ is to first set the image property to that last frame (while animationImages is still nil), then set the animationImages property and call startAnimating. When the animation completes, the image property is then displayed. No callback/delegate needed.