# Why does the animation bring objects back to their starting position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, animation

I have a view with objects the user can drag around and a couple of buttons that start animations. When the buttons are touched the animation starts, but all the objects go back to the starting position.. why?

```
NSMutableArray *arrayAntaChiusura1 = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    [arrayAntaChiusura1 addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                                   [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"anta_sx%d", 6-i]
                                    ofType:@"png"]]];
}

UIImageView *immagineAntaChiusura1;

immagineAntaChiusura1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(283, 82, 120, 130)];

immagineAntaChiusura1.animationImages = arrayAntaChiusura1;
immagineAntaChiusura1.animationDuration = tempo_ante;
immagineAntaChiusura1.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[immagineAntaChiusura1 startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:immagineAntaChiusura1]; // i think this line is the problem
```

thanks in advance for your help, i can't get out of this by myself!

Comment: What do you mean they go back to the start position? the first image? If you want the animation to repeat you have to set the animationRepeatCount to 0

Comment: what do you want to say?In your code images are changing frequently.What is your requirement

Comment: You mean all the objects go back to their starting position after the animation has finished? Because, that is expected behaviour.

Comment: I think your question is already answered here!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776516/can-i-stop-uiimageview-animation-at-last-frame

Look at the response from the user Bogdan

Comment: because always.. you add subview with UIImageView in the same location: ..CGRectMake (283, 82, 120…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your problem completely but If you want continuous animating objects then set repeat count to -1 that is equal to infinity as given below:-

```
UIImageView *immagineAntaChiusura1;

immagineAntaChiusura1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(283, 82, 120, 130)];

immagineAntaChiusura1.animationImages = arrayAntaChiusura1;
immagineAntaChiusura1.animationDuration = 1.5;
immagineAntaChiusura1.animationRepeatCount = -1;
[immagineAntaChiusura1 startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:immagineAntaChiusura1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My problem is not with the animation itself (it works fine), i have a few objects the user can drag around, the problem is that when one of those objects has been moved from its starting position, starting the animation brings it back to the point where it was when the view loaded, i don't know how to solve that. oh, and the animation doesn't involve the dragable objects, i don't know why it should move them too.

Comment: then you need to post the code where you are dragging the objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing the animation with the Images , You have to add those images in array smartly . Your code looks fine . Only one line in which I have doubt is :

```
[arrayAntaChiusura1 addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                               [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"anta_sx%d", 6-i]
                                ofType:@"png"]]];
```

All other is fine . Just check whether the images are arranged in the order or not .

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My problem is not with the animation itself (it works fine), i have a few objects the user can drag around, the problem is that when one of those objects has been moved from its starting position, starting the animation brings it back to the point where it was when the view loaded, i don't know how to solve that. oh, and the animation doesn't involve the dragable objects, i don't know why it should move them too.