# How to stop my animated button from looping constantly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I've just started trying to use animations in my IOS development, and I've managed to get one working when I click a button - however it repeats on a constant loop! 
How do I stop my animation from repeating after it's way through my .png sequence?

```
[measureButton.imageView setAnimationImages:images];
[measureButton.imageView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[measureButton.imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: I have found something there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11760933/5073674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the property `animationRepeatCount`.

```
[measureButton.imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];//The animation will repeat only once
```

the default value of this property (`animationRepeatCount`) is 0, which means the images are animated infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

you can call stopAnimating on your imageView when you have reached your last image.

Answer (score 0):

[measureButton.imageView stopAnimating];
hope this helps you out...